# How to install mod_auth_openidc module in an Apache server running on Docker

Tags: apache, openid-connect, keycloak, apache-modules

I am trying to add the [mod_auth_openidc module](https://github.com/zmartzone/mod_auth_openidc/releases) to an Apache server running on Docker. After adding `LoadModule auth_openidc_module modules/mod_auth_openidc.so`, I create the image and run it, getting this error:

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 69 of /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_auth_openidc.so into server: libcjose.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So I [downloaded that dependency](https://github.com/zmartzone/mod_auth_openidc/releases/download/v2.3.0/libcjose0_0.5.1-1.jessie.1_amd64.deb) and added the necessary LoadModule statement:

```
LoadModule libcjose_module modules/libcjose.so.0
```

Now the error is about libjansson.so.4:

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 68 of /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/libcjose.so.0 into server: libjansson.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I repeated the previous steps, downloading libjansson.so.4 from https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/libjansson4, adding it to he Dockerfile, the Apache configuration `LoadModule libjansson_module modules/libjansson.so.4` and:

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 67 of /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf: Can't locate API module structure `libjansson_module' in file /usr/local/apache2/modules/libjansson.so.4: /usr/local/apache2/modules/libjansson.so.4: undefined symbol: libjansson_module
```

So how can I load the jansson module???

This is my **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM httpd:2.4
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
curl
COPY ./libjansson.so.4 /usr/local/apache2/modules/libjansson.so.4
COPY ./libcjose.so.0 /usr/local/apache2/modules/libcjose.so.0
COPY ./mod_auth_openidc.so /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_auth_openidc.so
COPY ./my-httpd.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
```

And **httpd.conf**:

```
LoadModule libjansson_module modules/libjansson.so.4
LoadModule libcjose_module modules/libcjose.so.0
LoadModule auth_openidc_module modules/mod_auth_openidc.so
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of manually downloading the necessary libraries I moved that process to the Dockerfile, now the image is created correctly:

```
FROM httpd:2.4

COPY ./my-httpd.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
COPY ./server.crt /usr/local/apache2/conf/
COPY ./server.key /usr/local/apache2/conf/
COPY ./mod_auth_openidc.so /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_auth_openidc.so

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl && apt-get install -y libjansson4 && apt-get install -y wget && apt-get install -y libhiredis0.10 && apt-get install -y apache2-bin
RUN wget https://github.com/zmartzone/mod_auth_openidc/releases/download/v2.3.0/libcjose0_0.5.1-1.jessie.1_amd64.deb && dpkg -i libcjose0_0.5.1-1.jessie.1_amd64.deb
RUN wget https://github.com/zmartzone/mod_auth_openidc/releases/download/v2.3.3/libapache2-mod-auth-openidc_2.3.3-1.jessie.1_amd64.deb && \
dpkg -i libapache2-mod-auth-openidc_2.3.3-1.jessie.1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: where does ./mod_auth_openidc.so come from?

Comment: It's included in the distribuition of the module, for instance: `https://github.com/zmartzone/mod_auth_openidc/releases/download/v2.3.9/mod_auth_openidc-2.3.9-apache-2.4.x-win64.zip`

Comment: yeah just confused because I thought that the final 'RUN' line of your example was installing mod_auth_openidc.so

`RUN wget https://github.com/zmartzone/mod_auth_openidc/releases/download/v2.3.3/libapache2-mod-auth-openidc_2.3.3-1.jessie.1_amd64.deb && \
dpkg -i libapache2-mod-auth-openidc_2.3.3-1.jessie.1_amd64.deb`

Comment: Did you ever update the Dockerfile to wget/install all three pkgs from zmartzone?  Would also help if you post the relevant section of httpd.conf, thanks in adv.

Answer (score 5):

In 2021 the zmartzone module is available as a Debian package. So I was able to build an image using a simple Dockerfile, but I only need https (not php etc). I chose to use the httpd buster base image, in buster the zmartzone package version is 2.3.10.2-1, the latest and greatest today is 2.4.9.4.  Here's my Dockerfile, only two commands required:

```
# Build image with Apache HTTPD and OpenID connect module
FROM httpd:2.4-buster

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
    ca-certificates libapache2-mod-auth-openidc

# leave entrypoint etc. unchanged from base image
```

One thing I completely don't understand, that apache httpd base image
has modules in `/usr/local/apache2/modules` but the package installs auth_openidc_module in `/usr/lib/apache2/modules`. Maybe someone can explain that to me?

Anyhow, trying to make this answer complete, using this image requires changes to base image files `/usr/local/apache2/httpd.conf` and `/usr/local/apache2/extra/httpd-ssl.conf`. Here is the first set of diffs:

```
% diff httpd.conf.orig httpd.conf 
94c98
< #LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
---
> LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
142c146
< #LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
---
> LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
161c165
< #LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
---
> LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
199a204
> LoadModule auth_openidc_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_auth_openidc.so
241c246
< #ServerName www.example.com:80
---
> ServerName server.my.company.com:80
541c546
< #Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
---
> Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
```

Also extra/httpd-ssl.conf:

```
% diff httpd-ssl.conf.orig httpd-ssl.conf
125c129
< ServerName www.example.com:443
---
> ServerName server.my.company.com:443
290c294,319
< </VirtualHost>                                  
---
> OIDCProviderMetadataURL https://oidserver.my.company.com/.well-known/openid-configuration
> OIDCClientID my-company-client-id
> OIDCClientSecret my-company-client-scret
> OIDCRedirectURI https://server.my.company.com/secure/redirect_uri
> OIDCCryptoPassphrase my-company-crypto-passphrase
> 
> <Location /secure>
>    AuthType openid-connect
>    Require valid-user
> </Location>
> 
> </VirtualHost>
```

If your container does not trust the certificate used by your OIDC server, despite installing package ca-certificates, you may have to add this entry to your `httpd-ssl.conf` file but it's an ugly hack:

```
# https://github.com/zmartzone/mod_auth_openidc/issues/56
OIDCSSLValidateServer Off
```

In my deployment I chose to mount those httpd config files to the container, that avoids building the OID client secrets into the docker image. Here's a sample docker-compose.yml, on the `image` line use the tag you applied to the image built from the Dockerfile shown above:

```
version: "3"
services:
  # httpd starts as root, binds ports then switches to daemon (UID 1)
  httpd:
    image: httpd-openidc:local
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - /Users/me/apache-httpd/httpd.conf:/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
      - /Users/me/apache-httpd/httpd-ssl.conf:/usr/local/apache2/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
      - /Users/me/apache-httpd/my-dev.key:/usr/local/apache2/conf/server.key
      - /Users/me/apache-httpd/my-dev.crt:/usr/local/apache2/conf/server.crt
```

So far this works fine, HTH

(Updated Jan 2022 to install ca-certificates, thanks @uupascal!)

Comment: Great Tipp! One small caveat: I also had to install ca-certificates in order for the container to be able to trust the OIDC Endpoint.

Comment: Thanks @uupascal please show the command to add to the Dockerfile and I'll try it also. I changed the httpd-ssl.conf file to have `OIDCSSLValidateServer Off` which disables SSL checking. Your solution looks much better than my workaround!

Comment: Just modify `apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y libapache2-mod-auth-openidc` to be `apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y libapache2-mod-auth-openidc ca-certificates` :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the https://github.com/zmartzone/mod_auth_openidc/blob/master/Dockerfile-alpine to build the image and just do your post configurations specific for your site afterwards.

```
FROM alpine:3.10

ENV MOD_AUTH_OPENIDC_REPOSITORY https://github.com/zmartzone/mod_auth_openidc.git

ENV MOD_AUTH_OPENIDC_BRANCH master

ENV BUILD_DIR /tmp/mod_auth_openidc

ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/log/apache2

ENV APACHE_DEFAULT_CONF /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

# add testing repository (for cjose library)
RUN echo "http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing" >> /etc/apk/repositories

# ADD source
RUN mkdir ${BUILD_DIR}

# add dependencies, build and install mod_auth_openidc, need atomic operation for image size
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache \
  apache2 \
  apache2-proxy \
  wget \
  jansson \
  hiredis \
  cjose \
  cjose-dev \
  git \
  autoconf \
  build-base \
  automake \
  curl \
  apache2-dev \
  curl-dev \
  pcre-dev \
  libtool \
  && \
  cd ${BUILD_DIR} && \
  git clone -b ${MOD_AUTH_OPENIDC_BRANCH} ${MOD_AUTH_OPENIDC_REPOSITORY} && \
  cd mod_auth_openidc && \
  ./autogen.sh && \
  ./configure CFLAGS="-g -O0" LDFLAGS="-lrt" && \
  make test && \
  make install && \
  cd ../.. && \
  rm -fr ${BUILD_DIR} && \
  apk del git cjose-dev apache2-dev autoconf automake build-base wget curl-dev pcre-dev libtool

# configure apache 
RUN  apk add --no-cache sed && \
  echo "LoadModule auth_openidc_module /usr/lib/apache2/mod_auth_openidc.so" >>  ${APACHE_DEFAULT_CONF} && \
  ln -sfT /dev/stderr "${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log" && \
  ln -sfT /dev/stdout "${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log" && \
  ln -sfT /dev/stdout "${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/other_vhosts_access.log" && \
  chown -R --no-dereference "apache:users" "${APACHE_LOG_DIR}" && \
  apk del sed

# https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/stopping.html#gracefulstop
# stop gracefully when docker stops, create issue with interactive mode because it's the signal use by the docker engine on windows.
STOPSIGNAL WINCH

# port to expose, referes to the Listen 80 in the embedded httpd.conf
EXPOSE 80

# launch apache
CMD exec /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND -f ${APACHE_DEFAULT_CONF}
```